# How to achieve dotted grid image rasterization (responsive image alternative technique)?

Tags: css, image, responsive

I've stumbled over an interesting technique as an alternative to the classical way of providing different image files for different breakpoints, as seen on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200531095011/https://www.ews-schoenau.de/)

What they do is basically use the same masthead image of size 1024x1024 for all screen sizes / breakpoints. When the screen size is `>= 768 px` that image is then overlaid with a grid of black dots, which reminds one of the way pixels are arranged on tube monitors/TVs. This way the image can be stretched far beyond 1024px but still appear sort of sharp, because the black dots overlay any large pixels blocks and JPEG artifacts.

I can't seem to figure out how this is done on their page with CSS or JS. Is there any CSS or JS framework / plugin that does this out of the box or can anyone help with identifying the styles / code required to achieve this effect?

Comment: parent image `position: relative; z-index: 0` and its overlay (`::before`) `content: ''; position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%`. Maybe some additional fiddling, but this is the generic approach. Use of `z-index` is optional (`content` maybe optional too). Additionally, use an SVG pattern as overlay, better for scaling up/down.

Comment: And, of course, `::before { opacity: .25 }` (or some other low value), otherwise the overlay obfuscates the image. Use PNG with an alpha channel value 0 (very low) for any pixel in the overlay that needs to be invisible (hardly visible).

Comment: Ah thanks @RenevanderLende, i overlooked the `::before` selector in DevTools, now it becomes crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

To overlay an `<img>` with some other image (or text, for that matter) the general approach would be:

```
img {
    position: relative; /* make child elements move relative to this parent */
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
img::before {
    position: absolute; /* move this element absolute within parent */
    content: '';        /* needed as an empty :before will not get painted */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-image: "image-URL";

    ...
    additional background behaviour properties
    ...

    opacity: 0.25;      /* some low value for tranparency */

    /* either */
    width : 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* or */
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

It may be advisable to use either a PNG with alpha channel (for transparent pixels) or an SVG with some pattern (smaller in size, more accurate pixel painting/scaling when rezing the page, 'crispier').